# text subscript in kable col.names and header

Tags: r, kableextra

I cannot seem to produce an html table using the kableExtra package with column names or headers that contain subscripts.  I have tried multiple approaches but it just keeps showing the output without subscript.
Using the mtcars data set as an example:

```
data(mtcars)
library(kableExtra)

mtcars %>%
  filter(mpg == 21.0) %>%
  select(c(1:2)) %>%
  kable("html", col.names = c("m~pg~", "c\\textsubscript{yl}"), escape = F) %>%
  kable_styling()
```

I am trying to subscript the last two letters of the selected column names in this example for this html format table.  I have also tried using "$m~pg~$" and "$m_{pg}$" and "m\\textsubscript{yl}"

Comment: `m~pg~` works just fine for me.  I would not expect `\textsubscript{}` to work for html, since that's a LaTeX command (unless `kableExtra` is smarter about that than I know).  Have you tried looking at the output in different browsers?

Comment: I have only viewed the output in the RStudio viewer pane and in Chrome.  Both appear as **m~pg~** using the tilde syntax.

Comment: And...now it works today in my actual document :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The markdown notation is `^.^` and `~.~` to write super and subscripts.

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output:
  html_document
---

```{r}
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  filter(mpg==21.0) %>%
  select(c(1:2)) %>%  
  kable("html", col.names=c("m~pg~","c~yl~")) %>%
  kable_styling()
```
````

The output looks like this:
[image]

And just for completeness, if you wanted to do this for a PDF output then you can use latex commands.

```
mtcars %>% 
  filter(mpg==21.0) %>%
  select(c(1:2)) %>%  
  kable(col.names=c("m\\textsubscript{pg}","c\\textsubscript{yl}"), escape = FALSE) %>%
  kable_styling()
```

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this formatting behaviour in knitr 1.36 and kableExtra 1.3.4

Answer (score 2):

As @cengstro has pointed out, your solution does not work in `kableExtra 1.3.4`. For me the usual latex code works, e.g.

```
mtcars %>% 
  filter(mpg==21.0) %>%
  select(c(1:2)) %>%  
  kable(col.names=c("$m_{pg}$","$c_{yl}$")) %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F)
```

**Result:**

[image: kable_example]

Edit: If you do not want italics, you can use something like this:

```
mtcars %>% 
  filter(mpg==21.0) %>%
  select(c(1:2)) %>%  
  kable(col.names=c("$\\text{m}_{\\text{pg}}$","$\\text{c}_{\\text{yl}}$"), escape = F) %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F)
```