# Use superscript / subscript in kable r

Tags: r, kableextra

I want to put a superscript in a table header. I've tried like this:

```
require(kableExtra)
df <- head(mtcars[1:2]) 
df %>% kbl(col.names = c(expression("mpg"^"2"), "cyl"))
```

which just prints the literal code in the header.

[This response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59165188/text-subscript-in-kable-col-names-and-header) did not solve my issue, I think because I am not working in `Rmd`.

Advice welcome, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [text subscript in kable col.names and header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59165188/text-subscript-in-kable-col-names-and-header)

Comment: thanks @Limey, it didn't, have now edited question fwiw to reflect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work for your problem? (`kableExtra 1.3.4`)

```
library(kableExtra)
df <- head(mtcars[1:2]) 
df %>% kbl(col.names=c("$m_{pg}$","$c^{yy}$"))%>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F)
```

**Result**:

[image: kable_example]